# Installing GWT plugin for eclipse

Tags: eclipse, gwt

I have tried to install the GWT plugin for eclipse helios. when I try to I get this message:

> Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could
>   not be found.   Software being installed: Google Web Toolkit SDK 2.4.0
>   2.4.0.v201203300216-rel-r36 (com.google.gwt.eclipse.sdkbundle.e36.feature.feature.group
>   2.4.0.v201203300216-rel-r36)   Missing requirement: Google Plugin for Eclipse 3.6 2.5.2.v201203300216-rel-r36
>   (com.google.gdt.eclipse.suite.e36.feature.feature.group
>   2.5.2.v201203300216-rel-r36) requires 'org.eclipse.wst.css.core 0.0.0' but it could not be found   Cannot satisfy dependency:
>       From: Google Web Toolkit SDK 2.4.0 2.4.0.v201203300216-rel-r36 (com.google.gwt.eclipse.sdkbundle.e36.feature.feature.group
>   2.4.0.v201203300216-rel-r36)
>       To: com.google.gdt.eclipse.suite.e36.feature.feature.group 2.5.2..

Tried using both local files and downloading using eclipse. Nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/faq#wstinstallerror

You have to install WST first, and then you'll be able to install the Google Plugin for Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

This message generally says that there are problems when trying to connect to Helios update server. Because when installing GWT, you need extra package from it.

I met the similar(same ?) problem with Luna 64bit eclipse, when trying to install Google Plugins for Eclipse. This is solution I suggested:
1. Go to Preferences -> Install Update -> Available Software Update. 
2. Delete Helios entry. Quit eclipse. Make sure your network is ok. Reopen eclipse. Go back and re-add Helios entry. Click reload.
3. If no Helios entry is found in step 2, then simply add it and no need to do the else.