# plugin installation error

Tags: eclipse, gwt, plugins, eclipse-plugin

I just downloaded eclipse version Version: 3.7.0.Now for this eclipse I am installing gwt plugin for it.
Plugin link for this is: [gwt plugin](http://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/3.7) 
(http://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/3.7)
Now while installing I have checked to following items:

1. Google plugin for eclipse
2. Google app engine for java sdk 1.6.6
3. Google web tool kit SDK 2.4

All other check box are unchecked. 
Now on click on next at the time of installation it is giving me error like below:`Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: Google Plugin for Eclipse 3.7 2.6.1.v201205091048-rel-r37 (com.google.gdt.eclipse.suite.e37.feature.feature.group 2.6.1.v201205091048-rel-r37)
  Missing requirement: Google Plugin for Eclipse 3.7 2.6.1.v201205091048-rel-r37 (com.google.gdt.eclipse.suite.e37.feature.feature.group 2.6.1.v201205091048-rel-r37) requires 'org.eclipse.wst.server.core 0.0.0' but it could not be found`

I am not getting what is the issue.
Please help me out.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10245380/installing-gwt-plugin-for-eclipse

Answer (score 6, accepted):

WST is a requirement for Eclipse Google plugin. To make sure that this requirement is installed, make sure that the indigo update site(http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo) is added in the list of Available Software Sites. Also, before starting the installation of GPE, make sure that 'Contact all update sites during install to find required software' check box is checked.

This is an old [issue](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/google-web-toolkit/wu8GFnIo4SM) already reported in Google groups.

Answer (score 2):

The option `Contact all update sites during install to find required software` should be checked. In this case all missed dependencies will be installed automatically